# Is there a way in rails to find out what migrations have already been applied at run-time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to add the current migration level to an internal dashboard we use for server statistics?  Is there an easy build in way to support this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the contents of the migrations table directly. You'll get back an array of hashes containing everything in the migrations table, which will tell you which migrations are currently up:

```
# Get the SQL connection adapter
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

# Get the migrations table name
migrations_table = ActiveRecord::Migrator.schema_migrations_table_name

# Execute query
connection.execute("select * from #{migrations_table}")
```

Comment: For Rails 2.1 and above,  run migrations are stored in `schema_migrations` table in the db, so step 2 can probably be skipped and just do `connection.execute("select * from schema_migrations")`.    See:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html#class-ActiveRecord::Migration-label-About+the+schema_migrations+table